# Using for loop to display JSON contents in HTML div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to display the contents of my JSON into the div class "network-info". I believe what is being written first is then overwritten by what is next in the array. What can I use to circumvent this and show everything?

```
    $(function() {

        var netinfo = function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(".network-info").html(
                    "<hr>" +
                    "<p> Adapter Name: " + data[i].name + "</p>" +
                    "<p> IP Address:  " + data[i].ip + "</p>" +
                    "<p> MAC Address:  " + data[i].mac + "</p>" +
                    "<p> Adapter ID:  " + data[i].id + "</p>" +
                    "<hr>"
                )
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard?context=netadapters&node=5",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
        }).done(function(data) {
            netinfo(data);
        });

    });
```

Comment: you need to use .append instead of .html http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the output directly to HTML, build up a string and then inject the string, like this:

```
    var netinfo = function(data) {
        var output = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output +=
                "<hr>" +
                "<p> Adapter Name: " + data[i].name + "</p>" +
                "<p> IP Address:  " + data[i].ip + "</p>" +
                "<p> MAC Address:  " + data[i].mac + "</p>" +
                "<p> Adapter ID:  " + data[i].id + "</p>" +
                "<hr>";
        }
        $(".network-info").html(output);
    };
```

This is actually better than appending data, because it only modifies the DOM once.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for showing me the correct way to append data also!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the content of the `.network-info` element **is** being overwritten on each iteration of the loop.

I would suggest concatenating the string, and then setting the `.html` at the end.  This way the browser does not have to parse the HTML and update the DOM each time...

```
 var netinfo = function(data) {
    var htmlResult = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        htmlResult +=
            "<hr>" +
            "<p> Adapter Name: " + data[i].name + "</p>" +
            "<p> IP Address:  " + data[i].ip + "</p>" +
            "<p> MAC Address:  " + data[i].mac + "</p>" +
            "<p> Adapter ID:  " + data[i].id + "</p>" +
            "<hr>"
        )
    }
    $(".network-info").html(htmlResult);
};
```